# Seconds, minutes and hours since a date

Tags: bash, scripts, date

I would like to create a script that tells you how many seconds, minutes and hours have passed since a date (much like the `+%s` `date` command format). How can I subtract the current date with a specific date?
For example: how many seconds, minutes and hours have passed since 4th of July 1776.

Comment: The Perl module `Date::Calc` makes this easy, if you know Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
time=$(($(date -d"1776-07-04 00:00:00" +%s) - $(date +%s)))
```

sets a `time` variable you can use like so:

```
echo $time
-7595723059
```

The `+%s` tells `date` to format to `seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` which helps give us a starting point for doing the math in seconds.

Now it can also be added to a script with the same variables.

```
:~$ time=$(($(date -d"1776-07-04 00:00:00" +%s) - $(date +%s)))
:~$ printf '%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($time/3600)) $(($time%3600/60)) $(($time%60))
-2109923h:-12m:-55s
```

If you want Years:Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds since, it would be the following:

```
printf '%dy:%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($time/60/60/24/365)) $(($time/60/60/24%365)) $(($time/3600%24)) $(($time%3600/60)) $(($time%60))
```

Which would give you output like the following:

```
:~$ time=$(($(date -d"1776-07-04 00:00:00" +%s) - $(date +%s)))
:~$ printf '%dy:%dd:%dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($time/60/60/24/365)) $(($time/60/60/24%365)) $(($time/3600%24)) $(($time%3600/60)) $(($time%60))
-242y:-11d:-7h:-46m:-37s
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And how do I subtract 4th of July 1776 with the current date? I tried `$(($(date -d "1776-07-04 00:00:00") - $(date)))` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Cytotlewo You need to format the date into something that the math will understand.   Adding the `+%s` gives each date a reference point of `seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`

Comment: Oh wait, I think I got it. If I would like to know how many seconds have passed since 1776-07-04, I could subtract how many seconds have passed since 1970 with how many seconds have passed between 1970 and the specific date. So, it would be: `$(($(date +%s) - $(date '+%s' -d $1776-07-04)))` Correct me if I'm wrong. And if I would like to know how many minutes have passed, I'd have to divide it by 31536000 to get an approximate number. Sorry, I'm a slow thinker when it comes to these things.

Comment: @Cytotlewo Minutes would just be the number divided by 60 `/60`as there are 60 seconds in every minute.  To figure out how many hours it would be divided by 60 then 60 again `/60/60`, since there are 60 seconds in 1 minute and 60 minutes in 1 hour.  For days it would be divided by 60 then 60 and then 24 `/60/60/24`.  So, taking my first part that is `time=$(($(date -d"1776-07-04 00:00:00" +%s) - $(date +%s)))` to figure out the number of days it would be `days=$(($time/60/60/24))` then `echo $days` should show `-87913`.

Comment: Ohh, silly me. My subtraction was to figure out how many years have passed, since I divided it by the total seconds of a year (or am I wrong again? lol).

Comment: @Cytotlewo `years=$(($time/60/60/24/365))`

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with a dependency, the task is elegantly expressed using `dateutils`:

```
$ datediff 1776-07-04T00:00:00 now -f '%H:%0M:%0S'
2111284:08:34
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the package.