# A script or application to tell me how far apart two dates are

Tags: command-line, scripts, software-recommendation, time, date

I've got some files and for logging purposes I need to know how many days they are apart as well as potentially some other lengths. So I would like to have a script or application that:

- Can have two dates entered into it in the following format: `DD/MM/YYYY`
- Can optionally also have a time given to it in the format of `hh:mm:ss` in the 24-hour format
- Can be told if it should output the time between the two in either: seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or years.
- Preferably it would be nice if it could be asked to return more than just one amount of time between the two, so even if it outputs it in all those lengths then that is fine.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 with GNOME 3.24.1. If there are some commands which can do that that would be fine as well.

Comment: Could the date input format also be `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: @ByteCommander: Preferably not, but if it has to be it has to be.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/893758/231142) help?

Comment: @Terrance That is exactly what I was about to build... +1

Comment: @Terrance: That does make things a lot simpler... Though obviously my question is still slightly different to that one so some minor alterations will be needed. But than that one of you should be ready to post an answer.

Comment: The question is easy to answer, that is, once it is clear, but the second point makes no sense: *"Can optionally also have a time given to it in the format of hh:mm:ss in the 24-hour format"*. How would the script know the date if hours (in 24) are the largest given unit? Or are both times on the same day? Also: *"Can be told if it should output the time between the two in either: seconds, minutes, hours, days, months or years."*, meaning also *rounded* to those units? If so, rounded up, down or mathematical?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: The point would be that I would specify the date, and optionally also time time. I think it would be good for it to round up. Probably it will be good if the script just outputs the amount of years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds between the two dates. Even if some of these values are 0. If that is easier to do that is.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: You said that it could either be rounded up or down or "mathematical", what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `dateutils` is in most distributions and will accomplish this for you.

```
sudo apt-get install dateutils
```

The default seems to be in months with short dates.

```
$ dateutils.ddiff now "01/22/1992" -i "%m/%d/%y"
612
```

But the format string can be changed.

```
$ dateutils.ddiff now "01/22/1992" -i "%m/%d/%y" -f '%S'
52876800
```

As it appears to have built in timezone and locale support it would probably be a safer bet than trying to write a function off of epoch time.